# Spring Boot RollingFileAppender makes file but not appending anything

Tags: spring-boot, spring-logback

I'm using VScode connected to Ubunut through WSL to build SpringBoot project. Everything works fine. Now I'm trying to add logging to my project, and logback-spring.xml below is what I'm using as configuration. So far I can see that it works. I see console print, and it even makes `logback.log` file in the path I want. BUT, the file always seems to be empty. I tried to add some more logger here and there, and all I see is console output by ConsoleAppender.

```
<!--Logfile save path-->
<property name="LOGS_PATH" value="./logs"/>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d{HH:mm} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="SAMPLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}:%-3relative][%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="DAILY_ROLLING_FILE_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS_PATH}/logback.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}:%-3relative][%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_PATH}/logback.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- kb, mb, gb -->
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<logger name="com.qcells.olap" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="SAMPLE" />
</logger>
<logger name="com.qcells.olap" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="DAILY_ROLLING_FILE_APPENDER" />
</logger>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

In java code I use Logger like this: (Rx_Client2 is just name of the class including this code)

```
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Rx_Client2.class);        
logger.info("success");
```

I believe this is simple way to make log data, and I see print out of "success" message on my console.

I tried to delete logback.log file, and it re-makes the logback.log file when I run the project, but nothing written inside still.
Any solutions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your posted logback-spring.xml you definded three appenders. STDOUT,SAMPLE and DAILY_ROLLING_FILE_APPENDER. The first one STDOUT is assigned to the root logger

```
<root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

and therefore you see a log to the console when you log something to the

```
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Rx_Client2.class);
```

since the log message gets propagated up in the hierarchy of the loggers until it hits the root logger and the message gets handled by the appender attached to it.

The other two appenders are attached to specific loggers.

```
<logger name="com.qcells.olap" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="SAMPLE" />
</logger>
<logger name="com.qcells.olap" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="DAILY_ROLLING_FILE_APPENDER" />
</logger>
```

Is the Rx_Client2.class in a package below com.qcells.olap?

So only logs to loggers that reside below "com.qcells.olap" get logged into your rolling file. If you want all logs to be logged into the file you have to attach it to the root logger like the STDOUT appender.

```
<root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  <appender-ref ref="DAILY_ROLLING_FILE_APPENDER" />
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you! This really solved my problem.  But I got one more question if you don't mind. Rx_Client2 is located in com.qcells.ess_server.client . I fixed the path and tried it again but did not work. Any reason why root level works but path doesnt??